# How to register app launch listener in javascript for automation

Tags: macos, applescript, javascript-automation

I'm trying to build a script with javascript for automation to prevent certain applications from launching in OSX. In the documentation, there is a [NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSWorkspaceWillLaunchApplicationNotification) notification. How can I listen for this notification, check which application is being launched, and then stop the application from launching?

I'd like to be able to do it programmatically because I'm building an app for people to be able to block timewasting applications while they're working.

Comment: Why? The standard way to restrict the applications that can be launched is to create a 'Managed with Parental Controls' in the Users & Groups pane of System Preferences and configure it as appropriate.